# Unable to access/install xts package

Tags: r, macos, xts, installation-package

I am unable to install xts package on R version 3.3.0 on my macbook. I am getting following error:

> install.packages("xts", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
>
> Warning: unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3:
>     cannot open URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES'
>
> Warning message:
>   package ‘xts’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)

I also tried installing through "Package Installer" and it seems to have installed with no error/warning. However when I tried following:

> xts(rnorm(231),as.Date(13514:13744,origin="1970-01-01"))
>
> Error: could not find function "xts"

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Because "Package Installer" (presumably a Mac GUI pulldown menu choice) succeeded without error, then I suspect this was simply a case failing to use `library` to load the package before the `xts` call. It's always a good idea to `check` the 'install dependencies" box on that panel.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you try the CRAN version instead?

Just use

```
install.packages("xts", repos="http://cloud.r-project.org")
```

which should install just fine.  R-Forge is primarily a *source* repository so download and installation is not the primary use case and may be less stringently tested.

*Edit:* As as the OP appears to be posting simultaneously to the R-Forge lists (hint: don't do that; pick one venue and post just there) here is how you use it once installed:

```
R> library(xts)   # you need to load it
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

R> xts(1:5, Sys.Date()+0:4)
           [,1]
2016-05-22    1
2016-05-23    2
2016-05-24    3
2016-05-25    4
2016-05-26    5
R>
```